# Can I use assignment operator construction with more than 1 argument?

Tags: c++

Question may sound convoluted so here is the example:

```
std::string s = "1984"; // This calls constructor, not copy assignment
```

Now `std::string` has constructors that take more than 1 argument, for example count and char value.
Is there a way to use that constructor without explicitly calling it?

Reason why I can not use normal construction is that I want to use return value of a function to construct a nonspecific container user provides as long as that container has constructor taking 2 iterators(without bothering the user of my function to store return value and call the constructor).

Here is specific example of another code where single return value of a function can trigger the constructor call but IDK how to do that with multiple return values.

```
std::pair<const char*,const char*> last3_iter(const std::string s){
    assert(s.size()>3);
    return std::pair{s.data()+s.size()-3, s.data()+s.size()};
}

const char* last3_ptr(const std::string s){
    assert(s.size()>3);
    return s.data()+s.size()-3;
}

int main()
{
    {
    std::string s_ptr = last3_ptr("0123456789");
    std::cout << s_ptr << std::endl; 
    }
    {
    // Is it possible to rewrite last3_iter so 
    // that assignment operator does equivalent to this code?
    auto range = last3_iter("0123456789");
    std::string s_iter(range.first, range.second);
    std::cout << s_iter << std::endl; 
    }
}
```

Comment: last3_ptr is UB in C++11

Comment: A good compiler would optimize and remove that variable, if that is what you fear.

Comment: It is mostly about usability, I want users to be able to construct std::string and std::vector and std::unordered_set from return value of my function.

Answer (score 2):

You can by using `std::apply`, but it is a bit awkward:

```
struct X
{
    X(int, int);
};

auto get_params() -> std::tuple<int, int> { return {10, 20}; }
```

```
X x = std::apply([](int a, int b) { return X{a, b}; },
                 get_params());
```

---

You can make it user friendly by creating a simple utility function to hide that:

```
template <class T, class... Args>
auto apply_to_ctor(std::tuple<Args...> tp_args) -> T
{
    return std::apply([](Args... largs) { return T{largs...}; },
                      tp_args);
}
```

and then use as this:

```
X x2 = apply_to_ctor<X>(get_params());
```

For brevity I omitted using perfect forwarding. You need to do that. Also you might want to provide an overload to accept `std::pair`. This is just the basic ideea. You have to improve it.

Comment: Wow nice. But I doubt it's worth the effort :P

Comment: @Rakete1111 I would say so also. But nevertheless it is an option.

Answer (score 1):

Not with the design you currently have. Instead of returning the parameters to the constructor to call, why not return the object itself instead? You get copy elision (and RVO before C++17), so it has no performance penalty (it's a move in the worst case).

I don't know for sure what design you have in mind, but maybe you can do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
T last3_iter(const T& container) {
    assert(std::size(container) > 3);
    return T(std::next(std::begin(container), std::size(container) - 3), std::end(container));
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
auto s_iter = last3_iter("0123456789"s);
```

That would work for most (if not all) containers.

Comment: Like I said I do not want to limit the type of s_iter, so I want users to be able to construct std::string and std::vector and std::unordered_set from return value of my function. That is why I am stuck. I know how to use basic templates.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Then you can just pass another template parameter to `last3_iter`. Or do you mean you want to be able to construct several containers from only one function call?

Comment: No, just one container, but not know to me, aka user can provide any type as long as it has constructor taking 2 iterators.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Your function is not generic enough - I updated my answer, but I still don't really understand what your point is. Maybe you can provide a use case?

Comment: User wants to store subsequence of the string in container. I do not know what that container is. And I would like to not force user to specify it, so for example I would like to avoid auto result = last3<string>(str); I would prefer string result = last3(str); but I do not know how to do that